# How can HTML tags only be escaped in code and some tags not being escaped?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

When using certain online text editors (such as the text editor on Stack Overflow itself) we see that some tags like `<b>`, `<i>`, etc are allowed and in designated code sections all HTML tags are escaped.

How is that possible? I tried it by using jQuery and I think they use regular expressions, but I don't have much experience with using regular expressions.

I succeeded doing such things through jQuery AJAX and PHP scripts in which the result (which is escaped using `htmlspecialchars()` except certain allowed tags) is shown with jQuery's `.html()` function. However, I found that it is vulnerable to XSS attack. I also tried with `.text()`, but it escapes all tags including the tags I tried not to escape and AJAX loading also takes time.

How should I go about doing such a thing?

Comment: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stack Overflow, but it is in fact on-topic because it is about a programming technique, that merely happens to be used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: sorry, I _had_ to ruin it for you.

Comment: I actually did not mean exactly how stack overflow do this. I just want to know a way, how to escape some html tags in only in code and out of it tags remains unescaped only using jquery. Is it safe to display ajax response message in a div using `.html() not in .text() as I want some tags to be unescaped` when after using `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Have a look at HTML Purifier - you can specify very accurately which tags and attributes are permitted, and which should be stripped out. Things like `<b>` are in themselves safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tinymce as your editor and initialize that on a text area and after initializing it you can use

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    valid_children : "+body[style],-body[div],p[strong|a|#text]"
});
```

By doing this you allow editor you use only certain html tags rest will be escaped.

The valid_children enables you to control what child elements can exists within what parent elements. TinyMCE will remove/split any non HTML transitional contents by default. So for example a P can't be a child of another P element.

The syntax for this option is a comma separated list of parents with elements that should be added/removed as valid children for that element. So for example "+body[style]" would add style as a valid child of body.

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is a good start, but does not do any filtering on the server side; thus, a malicious user could inject whatever HTML they wanted.

Comment: It will never do validation on server side because its an jquery plugin for wysiwyg editor which runs of frontend not on server side. For server side you have to write your own regex to remove those tags.